# Random memory accesses are expensive?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, hash

During optimizing my *connect four game engine* I reached a point where further improvements only can be minimal because much of the CPU-time is used by the instruction `TableEntry te = mTable[idx + i]` in the following code sample.

```
TableEntry getTableEntry(unsigned __int64 lock)
{
    int idx = (lock & 0xFFFFF) * BUCKETSIZE;
    for (int i = 0; i < BUCKETSIZE; i++)
    {
        TableEntry te = mTable[idx + i]; // bottleneck, about 35% of CPU usage
        if (te.height == NOTSET || lock == te.lock)
            return te;
    }
    return TableEntry();
}
```

The hash table `mTable` is defined as `std::vector<TableEntry>` and has about 4.2 mil. entrys (about 64 MB). I have tried to replace the `vector`by allocating the table with `new` without speed improvement.

I suspect that accessing the memory randomly (because of the [Zobrist Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) function) could be expensive, but really that much? Do you have suggestions to improve the function?

Thank you!

**Edit:** `BUCKETSIZE` has a value of 4. It's used as [collision strategy](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table#Replacement%20Strategies-Bucket%20systems). The size of one TableEntry is 16 Bytes, the struct looks like following:

```
struct TableEntry
{                                       // Old New
    unsigned __int64 lock;              //   8   8
    enum { VALID, UBOUND, LBOUND }flag; //   4   4
    short score;                        //   4   2
    char move;                          //   4   1
    char height;                        //   4   1
                                        // -------
                                        //  24  16 Bytes
    TableEntry() : lock(0LL), flag(VALID), score(0), move(0), height(-127) {}
};
```

**Summary:** The function originally needed 39 seconds. After making the changes jdehaan suggested, the function now needs 33 seconds (the program stops after 100 seconds). It's better but I think Konrad Rudolph is right and the main reason why it's that slow are the cache misses.

Comment: Probably you should try changing `TableEntry te` to pointer, or even not use it at all, i.e `mTable[idx+i].height==NOTSET`, compilers nowadays know what is best for them.

Comment: Your last statement is correct, the # of entries isn't important it's how many accesses you are doing that will tell you what would work out better for you.

Comment: what about copying `TableEntry`? can it be optimized?

Comment: Can you append the compiler generated assembly code? There the performance problem will likely be more visible.

Comment: That's interesting.. I would think if you're hashing correctly, you wouldn't have a bottleneck issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point about copying the `TableEntry` is valid. But let’s look at this question:

> I suspect that accessing the memory randomly (…) could be expensive, but really that much?

In a word, **yes**.

Random memory access with an array of your size is a cache killer. It will generate lots of cache misses which can be [up to three orders of magnitude](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) slower than access to memory in cache. Three orders of magnitude – that’s a factor 1000.

<del>On the other hand, it actually looks as though you are using lots of array elements in order, even though you generated your starting point using a hash. This speaks against the cache miss theory, unless your `BUCKETSIZE` is tiny and the code gets called very often with different `lock` values from the outside.</del>

Comment: Repeated calls to the function *are* random, though.  The linear search kicks in for key collisions.

Comment: @user606723 “random” in “random access” means something different than you’re probably assuming. It means “arbitrary”, not necessarily  “stochastically distributed”.

Comment: You guys may have misinterpreted what I said. I was only agreeing with this point: "On the other hand, it actually looks as though you are using lots of array elements in order, even though you generated your starting point using a hash. This speaks against the cache miss theory, unless your BUCKETSIZE is tiny and the code gets called very often with different lock values from the outside."

Comment: If the table is properly sized, he is *not* using a lot of entries in a row:  That's a technique for dealing with key collisions in a hash table.  For good performance there should not be many collisions, thus the `for` loop in the original question should loop rarely or never.  The dominant factor in access order will be the sequence of arguments to `getTableEntry()`.

Comment: @Ben: I was uncertain about the algorithm but given the naming and usage, it sounds as though you’re right.

Comment: @Ben, Konrad Rudolph: Yes, `BUCKETSIZE` has a size of 4 and is used to handle collisions.

Answer (score 5):

You are making copies of your table entry, what about using `TableEntry&` as a type. For the default value at the bottom a static default `TableEntry()` will also do. I suppose that is where you lose much time.

```
const TableEntry& getTableEntry(unsigned __int64 lock)
{
    int idx = (lock & 0xFFFFF) * BUCKETSIZE;
    for (int i = 0; i < BUCKETSIZE; i++)
    {
        // hopefuly now less than 35% of CPU usage :-)
        const TableEntry& te = mTable[idx + i];
        if (te.height == NOTSET || lock == te.lock)
            return te;
    }
    return DEFAULT_TABLE_ENTRY;
}
```

Comment: And also maybe add a `const` variant (for usage within `const` methods)

Comment: Might be worth noting that if he doesn't want to change the "interface" to his method at all, the reference in the return value is unnecessary to gain most of the speed advantage here. He can still clone the return value while not cloning the intermediate values

Comment: It would be better if it were a `const TableEntry &` because the OPs current code will only be modifying a copy, not the actual entry, and this change will keep the OPs code honest.

Comment: Why not just return a const reference?

Comment: Yes that is true, thanks for the remarks. I suppose the OP is smart enough to know what should be done then. My change is definitively not having the same effect than the original code.

Comment: Just saying that changing the return value could break his existing code if mTable is disposed at any time while he is still using the returned reference. Just something to keep in mind, changing the return type is a potentially breaking change

Comment: @DeadMG, yes thanks, I edit it, anyway it wasn't so smart from me to return a non read-only reference to a static default value (that could then get modified for subsequent calls)

Comment: @DeadMG: I need a copy of the table entry because in the recursive game tree search the table entry could be overwritten. But I will try returning the reference and making the copy in the calling function.

Comment: If you assign the returned const reference to a value type, the copy will be performed, if you assign to a const reference type only the reference will be copied. The const is just there to ensure the original value is considered read-only. So by returning a const reference you have another (much smaller of course) performance benefit in cases where you would just want to have a look at the values.

Answer (score 4):

How big is a table entry? I suspect it's the copy that is expensive not the memory lookup.

Memory accesses are quicker if they are contiguous because of cache hits, but it seem you are doing this.

Comment: A table entry has 16 Bytes. Unfortunately the accesses are not contiguous because making a move on the board causes the hash-value of the old board `XOR`ed with a 64-bit value (every position on the board inherits a unique 64-bit value).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this exact problem with hash tables before.  The problem is that continuous random access to the hashtable touch all of the memory used by the table (both the main array and all of the elements).  If this is large relative to your cache size you will thrash.  This manifests as the exact problem you are encountering:  That instruction which first references new memory appears to have a very high cost due to the memory stall.

In the case I worked on, a further issue was that the hash table represented a rather small part of the key space.  The "default" value (similar to what you call `DEFAULT_TABLE_ENTRY`) applied to the vast majority of keys so it *seemed* like the hash table was not heavily used.  The problem was that although default entries avoided many inserts, the continuous action of searching touched every element of the cache over and over (and in random order).  In that case I was able to move the values from the hashed data to live with the associated structure.  It took more overall space because even keys with the default value had to explicitly store the default value, but the locality of reference was vastly improved and the performance gain was huge.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, could you please explain in more detail how you improved the performance with the default table entries (entries that are not set)?

Comment: In the case I encountered there were many objects and a small subset of them had additional data which was stored in a hashtable.  The idea was that a million objects might exist with only thousands or tens of thousands with non-default values.  So the hashtable was very "sparse" with respect to the key space.  I moved the data into the objects, including storing the default value repeatedly for the 900,000+ objects that didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers

```
TableEntry* getTableEntry(unsigned __int64 lock) {
int idx = (lock & 0xFFFFF) * BUCKETSIZE;

TableEntry* max = &mTable[idx + BUCKETSIZE];
for (TableEntry* te = &mTable[idx]; te < max; te++)
{
    if (te->height == NOTSET || lock == te->lock)
        return te;
}
return DEFAULT_TABLE_ENTRY; }
```

Comment: No – don’t. There’s absolutely no reason to put the shotgun barrel near your own foot. Furthermore, this code won’t compile since you’re using `te` as if it were a non-pointer value.

Comment: Should be faster than the other methods mentioned. Now, the only thing it's doing through the loop is incrementing a pointer and checking if it's below max.

Comment: @user606723 I can **guarantee** you in written, signed with my own blood, that it will not be one picosecond faster than the solution by jdehaan.

Comment: As long as the fact that mTable[idx + i] is executed over and over again doesn't cause issues. I've found that gcc doesn't optimize this as well as you would hope.

Comment: Not only will it not be significantly faster, but as written, it won't run... te.height and te.lock aren't defined anymore

Comment: Always nice to see pointer arithmetic in an OO programming language. Maybe const iterators are an option?

Comment: And, correct me if I'm wrong, but te is a pointer to a TableEntry, incrementing it by sizeof(TableEntry) will skip over a ton of records if TableEntry is bigger than a single byte

Comment: No, I am pretty sure it's ok. There exists a TableEntry in mTable every n bytes. Where n is the size of TableEntry. So, mTable+sizeof(TableEntry) == mTable[1]. In fact, if you want you could make the incrementor te[1] if you wanted.

Comment: Except you're not adding sizeof(TableEntry) BYTES, you're adding sizeof(TableEntry) * sizeof(TableEntry) BYTES, when incrementing a pointer C/C++ automatically multiples the operand by the size of the pointee...

Comment: @user606723 That’s not how pointer arithmetic works. Incrementing a pointer value of type `T` will increase its byte address by `sizeof T`.

Comment: "when incrementing a pointer C/C++ automatically multiples the operand by the size of the pointer" <- really? source?. EDIT: Ok, two people agree. Apparently I fail at pointer arithmetic.  I had the code like that originally but it seemed wrong for some reason.

Comment: @user606723: And THIS is why we don't recommend the OP switching to pointers. Also, would be nice if you post a comment/note when you edit your code to keep a bit of an audit trail, just so us commenters don't look like fools :)

Comment: @user606723: Also, just so you know, you misquoted me. C/C++ automatically multiples by the size of the POINTEE, not the POINTER